# Manually Deriving the Maximum Likelihood Estimates for Less Common Probability Distributions

Tags: r, probability, distributions, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have a question relating to **Manually Deriving the Maximum Likelihood Estimates for Less Common Probability Distributions**.

Suppose we generate 200 random numbers from a Normal Distribution ~ (1,2):

```
 [1]  1.397769643 -1.349810123  1.409096115  1.166556052  2.462052443  3.028535770 -1.857377329  0.065942000  0.351794046  2.147062096  2.363010032 -1.189474247
 [13]  3.442713676  0.351788119 -0.309373535  1.837829950  3.101517512  1.039759334 -0.301201509  1.535874305 -0.728008267  2.143456207  4.348591039  2.820767778
 [25]  3.496333171 -2.338135209  0.746765242  1.746013026  0.944348016  1.970963351  2.354741787  2.387481721  1.205882610  0.402545739  0.902755998 -0.642025338
 [37]  0.087375328  1.806437453  3.791417174 -0.589403950 -0.239511885  1.137691201  2.380651204  1.850905237  2.962715996  3.959523099  3.621970972 -1.058406304
 [49] -1.507255542 -1.885716470  1.135787149 -2.674447419  3.554089580  2.186803656  2.177498440 -1.036666961  3.498291156 -0.800947746  1.288569947 -2.301217797
 [61]  4.714108879  0.515299873  2.078148740  2.275190922  2.422285866 -0.149438329 -0.049109475  1.827983868 -0.896601107  0.440313103  1.334843025 -0.775672031
 [73] -0.837142576 -1.704267065 -2.688634934  1.996045412  2.808195823  1.854402259  0.052777805  2.900927434 -3.109949576  2.196366889  2.739805512  2.299826580
 [85]  1.057179217  0.814933668  0.420696242  0.850065781  2.249043234  1.600343804  0.479352527  1.666304984  0.473000452  0.999406254  3.067888101  3.128883912
 [97] -0.714565878  1.387855402  2.827717839  4.909632706 -0.008479906 -1.445391996  1.150020382  2.197519540  0.542254705  5.978928354  0.446459107  1.177704991
[109]  1.638146128  0.776432261  1.421044468 -2.076820462  1.350773328 -4.431283287  2.329737776  1.996587842  1.628355787  0.023008381 -1.408107937  2.005475065
[121] -0.860002975  0.859310023 -0.926337294  0.104039654 -0.661428856  0.031098359  1.686128381 -0.166502427 -0.548287576 -0.328115104  3.030054374  3.473628834
[133] -2.560485018  2.740471686  1.525781872  1.154106972  3.330453097  0.399179112  1.990016298 -0.940498588  1.683962236 -0.435178631 -0.025076808  0.822784836
[145]  0.010967310  0.827452539 -1.517881301  4.446102114  0.798512538  1.829764053  0.576889237  1.286887132  3.239158791  2.684281081  2.582538018  4.313381936
[157] -2.324854734  0.434557666  0.682587948  3.193361284  0.907390976  2.247828419 -0.919286073  0.135801307 -1.673057204  1.044632060  2.068368158  1.248012441
[169] -0.718772118  1.760703820 -2.243362849  3.569998000  2.246035684 -2.093363452  2.127768101  2.526914676 -0.181808756  1.633249166 -0.062230338  3.412009734
[181]  1.606922725  3.702113831  0.601343928  2.156066225  1.332592964 -0.035667929 -1.249321565  2.676814894  3.825397261  1.502243284 -1.436908125  1.173751825
[193]  2.495839812  2.137135555  0.491835980 -0.324536947  0.128536831 -0.478446746  2.658782246  4.427213921
```

By plotting the distribution of this data (I called this data "a"), it's reasonable to expect that this data might have come from a Normal Distribution (I did this using the R programming language):

```
plot(hist(a))
plot(density(a))
```

[image]

If we assume a Normal Distribution, Maximum Likelihood Estimation theory show us how to derive the estimators for the "mean" and "variance" of the Normal Distribution:

[image]

As a result, if we use the formulas for these estimators, our estimates will be pretty close to the actual values used to generate these points:

```
mean = sum(a)/200
[1] 1.057149


standard_deviation = sqrt(sum((a - mean(a))^2) / (200 - 1))
[1] 1.771531
```

**My Question:** How can we derive similar formulas for the Maximum Likelihood Estimates for less common distributions, such as the **Tweedie Probability Distributions**?

[image]

In R, random numbers from a Tweedie Distribution can be generated according to the following parameters (**"power"**, **"mu"**, **"phi"**):

```
library(tweedie)
y = rtweedie( 200, power = 1.2, mu = 1.5, phi = 1.2) 
hist(y)

y1 = rtweedie( 200, power = 2, mu = 1, phi = 1.5) 
hist(y1)
```

[image]

If we look at some of these randomly generated numbers from the Tweedie Distribution (power = 2, mu = 1, phi = 1.5):

```
  [1] 4.835229e-01 3.273596e-01 7.250924e-01 2.420644e+00 4.385017e-01 8.516473e-01 9.575440e-01 3.623502e-01 6.725927e-01 3.359006e-02 2.171428e+00 2.043827e+00
 [13] 7.253516e-02 4.601185e-01 1.381129e+00 3.434772e-01 3.124828e-01 2.210105e-01 5.395479e-01 7.862751e-02 2.240753e+00 1.200838e-01 5.442454e-01 6.421638e-01
 [25] 3.014555e+00 4.403903e-01 5.410043e-02 6.235082e+00 2.149887e-01 1.036470e+00 9.106634e-01 3.148187e-01 1.558772e-02 5.553067e-01 5.049492e-02 1.119339e+01
 [37] 1.034588e+00 2.013105e-01 1.766221e-01 4.711094e-01 5.075948e-01 1.982064e-01 2.532509e-01 7.562298e-01 1.856084e+00 4.363536e-01 1.787625e+00 1.198450e+00
 [49] 4.674783e-01 9.785719e-01 4.146315e-01 1.365006e+00 2.022401e-01 2.258816e-02 1.438350e+00 2.975052e-01 1.310374e+00 2.574818e-01 1.530184e+00 5.716808e-01
 [61] 1.006795e+00 2.789478e-02 2.110384e+00 6.499831e-01 2.293844e-01 8.956054e-03 5.910401e-01 2.473032e+00 8.723009e-01 4.730672e+00 1.072683e+00 2.961126e-02
 [73] 1.540705e-01 4.643479e-02 1.048683e-01 6.655147e-01 4.578233e-01 8.636943e-01 3.723237e-01 1.108970e+00 1.091554e+00 6.452105e-02 2.967971e+00 3.087451e+00
 [85] 2.542959e+00 3.112244e-02 7.727888e-01 9.219587e-01 1.239732e-01 4.568944e-01 2.543266e+00 2.355232e+00 1.806799e-01 1.652674e-01 8.144687e-02 1.190040e+00
 [97] 2.117846e+00 9.787840e-01 9.352342e-02 3.874447e-01 4.245093e+00 1.898894e+00 9.890710e-01 8.805150e-01 8.246694e-02 3.846567e+00 5.313029e-01 1.493798e+00
[109] 1.582339e+00 2.194297e+00 5.971556e-02 9.142690e+00 5.213884e-04 7.181976e-02 1.593938e+00 8.947677e-01 3.631769e-02 1.022450e-02 2.591273e-01 3.802100e-01
[121] 1.509313e+00 1.412009e+00 1.342824e-01 2.137578e+00 1.022353e-01 1.178305e-01 1.008145e+00 5.294744e-02 6.757453e-02 1.240903e+00 4.604285e-01 3.069427e+00
[133] 6.520134e-01 4.636159e-01 2.093750e+00 1.804378e-01 3.066245e-01 1.611355e+00 8.780143e-02 2.801444e-01 1.074960e+00 2.617296e-01 1.509953e+00 2.612716e-02
[145] 8.929552e-03 1.681465e+00 8.246581e-01 2.288786e+00 2.032069e+00 8.485531e-01 9.085607e-01 5.273483e-01 6.169230e-02 1.814618e-01 1.481157e+00 2.420769e+00
[157] 1.078106e-01 1.582527e+00 1.264192e-01 1.481463e+00 2.316226e-01 7.622064e-01 4.965801e-01 2.422014e+00 1.153327e+00 2.873479e+00 2.011737e-02 6.827516e-01
[169] 6.406967e-01 5.710539e-01 4.386122e-01 6.174785e-01 7.832803e-02 5.669017e-03 8.192740e-01 1.158842e-01 8.627114e-01 3.967166e-01 2.668195e+00 3.451398e+00
[181] 1.994125e-01 4.742352e-01 1.986717e+00 1.184821e+00 4.672017e-01 4.829571e+00 7.589721e-02 7.405997e-02 6.214423e-01 5.717092e+00 3.910497e-01 1.104365e+00
[193] 8.593129e-01 1.996427e+00 4.901073e-01 1.831476e-01 9.505221e-02 3.102266e+00 1.617453e-03 1.186391e+00
```

Can we also use MLE to derive the formulas for the "power", "mu" and "phi" parameters? Suppose we know the probability distribution formula for the Tweedie Distribution (linked above) - can someone please show me how the derivatives of the log-likelihood function for the different model parameters of the Tweedie Distribution can be written, optimized and calculated? Given the 200 randomly generated numbers from the Tweedie Distribution - if we used the MLE formulas, would they return values of "power", "mu" and "phi" close to  2,  1 and 1.5?

Thanks!

Comment: The question as stated for "less common distributions" is far too broad (and vague--what might the "common" distributions be?) for this site, but interpreting it literally as for Tweedie distributions only makes it sufficiently focused to be answerable.

Comment: Find the likelihood function, take the logarithm to convert products into sums, take the derivative, find where the derivative equals zero, and determine which of those points is the highest. It’s the usual from calculus, just with nasty functions that might not have decent derivatives for by-hand calculations.

Comment: In general you can't solve MLEs in closed form. Typically you have to use 
numerical optimization methods to find the argmax of the (log-)likelihood
and further numerical calculation to obtain approximate standard errors and
covariances if required.

In the case of the Tweedie, if you fix the power parameter, $p$, you have a GLM. 
This is particularly convenient as you can use that to compute the profile likelihood 
at any particular $p$, and hence, by iterating calls to GLM, obtain a numerical
ML estimate of the parameter $p$, and then obtain the ML estimates of the remaining ... ctd

Comment: ... parameters from the GLM at that value of $p$. This is similar to the method used by MASS 
(which comes with R but is one of a number of packages in the distribution of R but which are not 
loaded by default) to compute the theta parameter in a negative binomial regression 
(see `glm.nb` in `MASS` and the corresponding book by Venables and Ripley). GLMs, being exponential family, have nice sufficient statistics, which makes them relatively simple to fit compared to the general ML case and optimization of a single parameter is simpler. There's an R package for Tweedie models

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies! I realize that the estimates for "power", "mu" and "phi" will require some numerical optimization method (compared to the normal distribution in which the maximum likelihood estimates for "mu" and "sigma" have a closed form solution). I was just curious to find a reference that explains how to set up the equations for "mu", "phi" and "power" so that a computer can solve them. For instance, there is a "summation over infinity" in the likelihood equation: how can we handle this in the mle process?

Comment: 1. My apologies; I misremembered above estimating the dispersion parameter presents difficulties as well; you can still use a GLM to marginalize $\mu$, though. Indeed just computing the  density or log-density and its derivatives with respect to the parameters is a nontrivial task.  ... 2. The GLM book by Dunn and Smyth has a chapter on the Tweedie GLM. ... 3. Are you just concerned about fitting a single distribution to a whole data set?

Comment: Some references - 
1. Peter K Dunn and Gordon K Smyth. “Evaluation of Tweedie Exponential Dispersion
Model Densities by Fourier Inversion”. In: Statistics and Computing 18.1 (2008),
pp. 73–86.
2. Peter K Dunn and Gordon K Smyth. “Series Evaluation of Tweedie Exponential
Dispersion Model Densities”. In: Statistics and Computing 15.4 (2005), pp. 267–
280.
3. Peter K Dunn and Gordon K Smyth. “Tweedie family densities: methods of evaluation”. In: Proceedings of the 16th International Workshop on Statistical Modelling,
Odense, Denmark. 2001, pp. 2–6.

Comment: 4. Smyth, G.K. and Jørgensen, B.(2002) “Fitting Tweedie's compound Poisson model to insurance claims data: dispersion modelling”, ASTIN Bulletin 32, 143–157  https://www.casact.org/sites/default/files/old/astin_vol32no1_143.pdf ... 5. Power-variance models for modelling rainfall
Peter K Dunn and Neil White  https://eprints.usq.edu.au/734/1/Dunn-White-pvar.pdf

Comment: functions like `dtweedi`e can be called to evaluate the density (and hence the likelihood) and if you have a derivative-free optimizer you don't need to worry about evaluating derivatives to maximize the likelihood, but that can be slow.